# Topology induced by convergent sequences

Tags: general-topology

Suppose I have a set $X$ and a set of sequences $\Sigma =\{(x_\bullet \in X)_\alpha\}$, as well as an assignment $\Sigma \to X$ that assigns each sequence a set of limits $L_\alpha \in X$. The question is, what's the finest topology on $X$ such that each sequence has $(x_\bullet)_\alpha \to l$, $l \in L_\alpha$?

The natural thing to consider is the topology $\mathcal T$ generated by the sequentially closed subsets, however, I'm stuck in one step on proving this is the topology I'm looking for:

Partial proof. Suppose $\mathcal T'$ is another topology on $X$ that has all the limits of sequences as specified. Let $U$ be a closed set of $\mathcal T'$. It then follows that $U$ is sequentially closed in $\mathcal T'$. We need to show that $U$ is sequentially closed w.r.t. the limits in $\Sigma, L$. Suppose $y_n \in U$ has $y_n \to k$. *Then $y_n \to k$ must follow from purely toplogical/sequential reasons, so $y_n \to k$ must also hold in $\mathcal T'$*. Hence, $k \in U$ as desired.

The problem is clearly the step in italics, as it's not very rigorous. How could this argument be fixed/completed? Any alternative, rigorous, argument would also solve this question.

Comment: It could be characterised as the universal topology such that the functions $x_\bullet:\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}\to X$ are continuous for all $x\in\Sigma$, using the one point compactification

Comment: Good point! Then I can use the concrete characterization of the final topology, and check if my definition of $\mathcal T$ coincides. Still wondering if my incomplete argument can be fixed.

Comment: Let's start with the fact that an arbitrary choice of sequences and limit assignments may not result in a topology at all. For example $L_a$ has to be equal to $L_b$ if $a$ is a subsequence of $b$. And that's not the only necessary behavior of convergent sequences. Another one is that eventually constant sequence has to have this eventually constant value as limit. And more.

Comment: @freakish I think that is incorrect. The question required the finest topology such that the sequences converge to the indicated limits. However the same sequences could converge to more limits, or other sequences may converged to unspecified limits. All that should be fine. The indiscrete topology satisfies the requirement, and the poset of topologies that satisfy the requirement is closed under joins, so such a topology *does* exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought, FShirke's answer works well:

The idea is exploiting that $x_n \to l$ iff $f:\mathbb{N} + \{\infty\} \to X$ is continuous, with $f(n)=x_n$ and $f(\infty)=l$. Then, the topology $\mathcal T$ is the final topology w.r.t. the $f_\alpha$. Expanding definitions, we see that $U$ is closed in $\mathcal T$ iff any tail $x_n$ is in $U$ implies that $l$ is in $U$, which is the precise form of requiring that $U$ be sequentially closed w.r.t. the $x_n$.